# How to download GDB debugger on mac yosemite

Tags: gdb, tar

this is the link for the debugger download: 
http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/download/ 
I clicked on the first link and downloaded 7.10 but I'm not sure how to unpack this file extension gdb-7.10.tar.xz.sig. 
I tried the following command which did not work `$ tar xf gdb-7.10.tar.xz`.

Comment: Install [homebrew](http://brew.sh) and then `brew install gdb`. Or learn to love lldb like all the cool kids these days.

Comment: I get the error 'Error: No available formula for gdb' when i do that

Comment: OK - it should work - see: http://www.patosai.com/blog/post/installing-gdb-on-mac-os-x-yosemite - if not then consider learning to use the standard Apple lldb instead - it's better than gdb in a lot of ways"